# Possible for certain black holes to transform into neutron stars?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, neutron-stars

Considering that space-time is expanding at an increasing rate or perhaps during times of inflation - could a black hole just above the neutron star threshold experience a decrease in density to switch back to a neutron star?

Edit: That is, same mass/energy as before but it's now contained in a volume greater than the Schwarzschild  radius due to expansion (current or future or inflation era) in the fabric of space time itself.

PS: I'm **not** talking about that process by energy or mass escaping it ([as discussed here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290753/can-a-stellar-black-hole-revert-into-neutron-star-or-whatever-it-was)).

Comment: Spacetime won't expand locally, see [more here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258479/) and the link in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33386/will-the-big-rip-tear-black-holes-apart

Comment: also see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118930/248459

Answer (score 2):

No. According to accepted theory, a black hole generally can't lose energy or mass. Even with Hawking radiation, the black hole would simply change size accordingly and remain a black hole. Once it got too small it would evaporate into a burst of Hawking radiation.

I know you say you aren't talking about energy or mass escaping the black hole, but the idea of black holes is that they are a one-way process.

I fail to see how the linked article isn't an answer to your question.

Comment: same mass/energy but now contained in volume exceeding Schwarzschild  radius due to space-time expansion

Answer (score -1):

Spacetime does not expand at scales comparable to a Schwarzchild radius, or a solar system, or even a galaxy. Not trying to be a smarty-pants, but for the benefit of all, please get the basics under wraps before moving into conjecture.

Comment: For the benefit of all, can you be more specific about the rate mismatch? Expansion rates from the past. present or future predicted?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to construct a cohesive answer?

Comment: The answer seems to contradict the big rip https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip