# Fast rotating black holes converting into neutron stars

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, neutron-stars, black-hole-firewall

I know that there are some researchs about neutron star slower their spinning  they can transform into black holes.

Is there any research about the reverse process? Going from a black hole of 1 $M_{\odot}$ into a neutron star? Is this conflicting with the information paradox?

Comment: This doesn’t happen.

Comment: Matter can’t escape from a black hole except through Hawking radiation.

Comment: How would you increase the angular momentum of a black hole without increasing its mass?

Comment: I think I should close this as this question have been done in the past: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118930/will-a-black-hole-eventually-turn-into-a-neutron-star?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @G.Smith general relativity is time reversible, so the process should be possible, even if less likely than a broken eggshell being rebuilt by chance, right?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny - The time reversal of a black hole is a white hole, where matter can't stay inside.

Comment: @mmesser314 Thanks, I am likely going to post it as a separate question, I read that answer before but still does not make full sense to me, specifically why not every possible process is not in principle time reversible

Comment: @safesphere it makes sense, thanks. And from the point of view of an observer that actually falls and sees himself crossing the horizon, I assume that reversing the momentum after the crossing will not make him cross the horizon back, correct? if that is the case, why these "solutions" (I dont know how to call them) are not time reversible?

Comment: @safesphere but there are many answers here that contradict you in your last statement, they claim that an observer crossing the horizon does not experience anything weird, other than spaghetification if tidal forces are too large

Comment: @safesphere great, thanks for all your explanations!