# Is it possible for a particle to orbit a singularity inside the event horizon

Tags: black-holes, orbital-motion, singularities, event-horizon

Event horizon just means a distance from singularity, where there is no "going-away" from the black hole. But is it possible, that there are particles with enough momentum to actually orbit the singularity under the event horizon?

Comment: Relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206587/do-particles-in-a-black-hole-stay-in-constant-orbit

Comment: This question however discusses orbits outside of the event horizon. I am rather interested of what happen inside.

Comment: Read it again, both cases are there.

Comment: As has been mentioned on this site in numerous answers to black hole questions, the forward time-like direction is, within the horizon, towards the singularity (as usual, we assume the Schwarschild black hole context).  That is, whatever it is that compels objects to 'move' forward in time compels objects to approach the singularity (if within the horizon).  To have a fixed radial coordinate (circular orbit) within the horizon is as impossible as it is to have a fixed time coordinate.