# A question about Kerr black holes and Hawking radiation

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation, hawking-radiation, kerr-metric

It's a common myth that somoene falling into a black hole will see the entire history of the universe before they cross the event horizon.

With a Kerr black hole however, it's sort of true. The inner horizon is an infinite blueshift surface meaning that a falling observer will observer the entire history of the universe (until they are vaporized by blue shifted radiation.)

[https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/rn.html](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/insidebh/rn.html)

However when we take into account Hawking radiation, an issue comes up.
Hawking radiation gives all black holes a finite lifetime.
Shouldn't it be impossible to actually ever cross the inner horizon as a result of the Hawking radiation?

Just to be clear, I’m not talking a about a Schwarzschild black hole, but a Kerr black hole.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does any particle ever reach any singularity inside the black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3706/)

Comment: No, that question does not answer my question.

Comment: I do not agree that it is a duplicate, since it is about an inner and not event horizon, so voting to reopen (though this question does display misconceptions about black holes, just a different set than the marked one).

Comment: Really want an answer to this.